# Remove Business Tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

[business](/questions/tagged/business)  Wiki Tag

```
DO NOT USE - Removed as part of "The great Stack Overflow tag/question cleanup of 2012" - See link in Tag Wiki for more information.
```

I wish to burninate this tag, how ever there are 440 QUESTIONS that are tagged in it. Also I wish for this tag to never appear again, as its tag says it has already been cleaned up in the Great Stack Overflow 2012 but it is still here. Maybe a burnination and a blacklist request.

**update**

The number of question increased  ask for other MODS or people to clean this tag up. If burnination is applicable that would be preferable Apr. 3 2014.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please vote to close/delete any questions tagged [business](/questions/tagged/business) that are off-topic and leave the tag in place so that we can clean up the questions and not just the tag.

Only *remove* the tag from questions that are on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: As a general guidline, something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593651/what-do-you-do-when-every-possible-business-idea-is-already-taken) is completely off-topic.. right? I don't want to start casting close/delete votes just in case it is, in fact, on-topic.

Comment: @JoshC Yes, I closed that one as "too broad." A case could be made for "primarily opinion based" as well.

Comment: i cant vote to close :( sorry. @BilltheLizard

Comment: @AsshO.Le That's ok. I closed over 20 of them from the review queue this morning, so someone is voting to close them.  Hopefully they keep it up, and more people join in.

Comment: Most of them are utter dog sheet.  And some of them you participated in :)

Comment: Bill, this policy leaves the tag attracting new bad questions. Isn't there some other way?

Comment: @Rosinante I think there are few enough questions with the tag now that we can do away with it. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I can tell you from examining them that all the remaining questions that have the tag deserve deletion, or at least closure and retagging with some 'this is a dud' tag.

Comment: @Rosinante Agreed. I went through the last 50+ last night and didn't see a single salvageable one. That tag is no more.

Answer (score 2):

This is really bad tag, what worse it attracts very bad questions. I've used all my close flags for today. This is what I suggest for the most common cases under that tag (and similar such as [project-management](/questions/tagged/project-management):

- what-should-i-do questions: **off-topic -> no effort**
- what-is-better: **primary opinion based**
- what-should-i-use: **off-topic -> recommendation**
- questions about business processes: **off-topic -> other -> business/project management**
- design questions: **off-topic -> other -> UI design**

I recommend **blacklisting** [business](/questions/tagged/business) and any similars such as [project-management](/questions/tagged/project-management), [software-development](/questions/tagged/software-development) etc.

Comment: This is what i also want to black list it its been a while of flagging and editing questions inside but you see i cannot do this alone and i need more backup! i almost run out of ammo everyday but they just keep on coming! waa!