# Blacklist godaddy tag, and rename to godaddy-api

Tags: support, tags, tag-block-request

There are 1314 questions tagged with [godaddy](/questions/tagged/godaddy) despite the request to "burninate" it [earlier](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177489/burninate-the-godaddy-tag) and I think that it needs some love, the problem is that we would go against the tide of questions about general programming questions which incidentally the provider is GoDaddy, questions about the GoDaddy API, and full blow questions about GoDaddy which has nothing to do with programing. We would need to evaluate, close and retag most of them organically, but with new questions being created at the same time, such task will be difficult.

I propose to blacklist the tag, so that users can slowly but surely remove the tag.

Comment: There is no routine tag blacklisting feature on the SE platform.  Blacklisting is expensive from a performance standpoint, so it is only used in the most extreme cases.  More info here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/blacklist-request/info

Comment: Taking a quick look at a few questions under that tag, most of them seem to be referring to Go Daddy The Hosting Provider, not Go Daddy the API.

Comment: @RobertHarvey but, still would need manual reviewing. And also, it demotivates users to try to accomplish a task, and see the goal just moving farther away (if they fix 15 Q/day, there will be 14 new questions meanwhile (average)).

Comment: Most GoDaddy The Hosting Provider questions can be closed as off-topic, I would imagine.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I was thinking about [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209091/213575)